# Thermostat replacement

Tags: hvac, thermostat

My old thermostat is a carrier t-stat and has a jumper wire between o/w2* and L

I am upgrading to a honeywell wifi t-stat, should I install the same jumper wire on the new thermostat?

I have an outdoor heatpump system carrier tech2000ss
The furnace is a carrier weathermaker 9200

Picture of old thermostat:
[image: Here is a picture of the old thermostat wiring:]

New thermostat:
[image]

Comment: You should read and follow the documentation that comes with the new thermostat. The `L` terminal is usually used for some type of indicator (usually a light), and may not be on all thermostats. If this is for a heat pump system, the `O` terminal will control the reversing valve. When it's energized the system should be in cooling mode, when it's not the system is in heating mode. If there is a jumper from `O` to `L`, my guess would be that there's some type of light that indicates the current mode.

Comment: I did read the documentation but it never blew cold when hooked up.

Comment: I had the white wire hooked into W1 and the orange wire hooked into W2, then I read online that the orange wire o/w2 needed to be hooked into W1 o / b on the new thermostat - which I did, and the white needed to be hooked into the W2/Aux terminal - I did this and it still blew hot for the AC.

Comment: This is for a heat pump system

Comment: I added a picture of the new thermostat

Comment: Can't see the labels on the old board, since the wires are in the way. Typically `W` is the white wire, and is used to call for heat. `Y` uses the yellow wire, and is used to call for cool. The sure fire way to determine which wires go where, is to go to the air handler and see where they all connect.

Comment: Do you have a heat pump, and a furnace as a backup? Or do you use the furnace for heating, and a condensing unit outside for cooling?

Comment: Condensing unit outside is used for cooling, furnace is used for heating. I believe **

Comment: I photoshopped arrows into the first image with the wire color & terminal, I can do so for the new stat but it goes: orange = w1/ o / b , yellow = y1, green = g, white = w2 / aux

Comment: Then you don't have a heat pump.   Hook it up white to `W`, yellow to `Y`, green to `G`, orange to `W2` or `O` depending on how it's wired in the furnace. Do you have 2 stage heat?

Comment: Can't see the labels on the new thermostat.

Comment: The condensing unit outside says carrier ts9000s with heat pump on the side - Looking up my furnace type carrier weathermaker 9200 it says it is single stage. I will get a better picture of the new thermostat as well.

Comment: Maybe it is a heat pump then. In which case, the orange wire is used to switch the reversing valve to cooling mode.

Comment: Mark your answer and I will accept it - I got it to work.

Comment: You should create an answer yourself. Include everything you did, and possibly some photos of the before and after. This information could be useful to future visitors. I'm glad the information I provided was helpful.

Comment: I found a similar Honeywell thermostat, and it appears the first terminal on the right is `W-O/B`. This is worrisome, since it appears your system uses both the `W` and `O`.  I'm not sure what the `O` is used for in your application, but you might want to do some poking around in the furnace to find out. What were the final connections you made to get it working?  Is it working properly now?

Comment: I might be wrong, I have to investigate more. It ends up I turned the heat on but it wasn't really hot. But I read that heat pumps are not supposed to be as hot as forced air. It works if I change settings, but I think I am going to have to call a pro in to see what is going on. I will take a picture of the terminals on the furnace